# Full screen overlay menu with HTML,CSS,JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to make a full-screen overlay navigation menu. And I don't know what am I doing wrong.
So I am using a checkbox as a toggler for the fullscreen navigation menu. And also using a hamburger for the button.

This might have a small error that I don't seem to find but I am a beginner in this.
please help

this is Html code

```
<body>
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fullpagemenu" id="menu">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="Team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="landing">
  <img src="./circles.svg" alt="dots">
  <h1>Dots</h1>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

this is index.js. This is also working fine as it toggles the active class in fullpagemenu div

```
const toggler = document.querySelector(".toggler");
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

toggler.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

this is index.css. Everything works fine when I set the top to 0 in fullpagemenu class.

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.fullpagemenu{
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.fullpagemenu .active{
  top: 0%;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul{
  position: relative;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li:hover:before{
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: top;
}
.fullpagemenu .nav ul li a{
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding-top: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li a:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li:hover a {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  color: black;
}


.landing{
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.landing h1{
  margin: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: purple;
}


/* MENU STYLES */
.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Hamburger Line */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* Hamburger Lines - Top & Bottom */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
}

/* Moves Line Down */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  top: 10px;
}

/* Toggler Animation */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Turns Lines Into X */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Rotate On Hover When Checked */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

Comment: use z-index to make it above the content, and give z-index body too

Comment: `.fullpagemenu .active` selects an `.active` element *inside* a `.fullscreen` element; you need to use `.fullpagemenu.active` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a space between the `.fullpagemenu .active` and it should be: `.fullpagemenu.active` edit this and your code works:

```js
const toggler = document.querySelector(".toggler");
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

toggler.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menu.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.fullpagemenu{
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.fullpagemenu.active{
  top: 0;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul{
  position: relative;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li:hover:before{
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: top;
}
.fullpagemenu .nav ul li a{
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding-top: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li a:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
}

.fullpagemenu .nav ul li:hover a {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  color: black;
}


.landing{
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.landing h1{
  margin: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: purple;
}


/* MENU STYLES */
.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Hamburger Line */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* Hamburger Lines - Top & Bottom */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
}

/* Moves Line Down */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  top: 10px;
}

/* Toggler Animation */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Turns Lines Into X */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Rotate On Hover When Checked */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fullpagemenu" id="menu">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="Team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="landing">
  <img src="./circles.svg" alt="dots">
  <h1>Dots</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Ohh! my bad. That was a quickie. But can I ask the logic behind it? the other selections have spaces too. and thanks a lot :)

Comment: look at the comment by Chris G, he was quicker and has a good explaination. it's basicly when using a space, going to select a child of the previous selected element, having no space however selects an element that matches both selections